# Python Scrapy keep getting same page link from next page button

Tags: python, html, xpath, css-selectors, scrapy

i am trying to scrape amazon.com for the link of products that has more than 800 reviews but i keep getting the same page link from the next page button it keeps returning page 2 over and over again where i should get page 3,4 and so on

*I HAVE SET A IF CONDITION TO SPILT AND CONVERT REVIEW STRING LIKE 1,020 TO INTEGER AND COMPARE IF GREATER THAN 800 OR NOT THEN BASED ON THAT VISIT THE PAGE*

**here is the code**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from amazon.items import AmazonItem
from urlparse import urljoin


class AmazonspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "amazonspider"
    DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_165993011_nr_n_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A165793011%2Cn%3A%21165795011%2Cn%3A165993011%2Cn%3A2514571011&bbn=165993011&ie=UTF8&qid=1493778423&rnid=165993011']


    def parse(self, response):


        SET_SELECTOR = '.a-carousel-card.acswidget-carousel__card'
        for attr in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
            #print '\n\n', attr

            item = AmazonItem()

            review_selector = './/*[@class="acs_product-rating__review-count"]/text()'
            link_selector = './/*[@class="a-link-normal"]/@href'

            if attr.xpath(review_selector).extract_first():
                if int(''.join(attr.xpath(review_selector).extract_first().split(','))) >= 800:
                    url = urljoin(response.url, attr.xpath(link_selector).extract_first())
                    item['LINKS'] = url
                    if url:
                        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_link, meta={'item': item})  


            next_page = './/span[@class="pagnRA"]/a[@id="pagnNextLink"]/@href'
            next_page = response.xpath(next_page).extract_first()
            print '\n\n', urljoin(response.url, next_page)
            if next_page:
                yield scrapy.Request(
                    urljoin(response.url, next_page),
                    callback=self.parse
                )
    def parse_link(self, response):

        item = AmazonItem(response.meta['item'])

        catselector = '.cat-link ::text'
        defaultcatselector = '.nav-search-label ::text'
        cat = response.css(catselector).extract_first()
        if cat:
            item['CATAGORY'] = cat
        else:
            item['CATAGORY'] = response.css(defaultcatselector).extract_first()
        return item
```

**here is the output when i was printing the next page link before calling the parse function recursively**

[image: here]
and [image: here]

and here is the screenshot from the next page selector of the page
[image: here]
***where am i going wrong ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the next page code block outside the loop.

```
class AmazonspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "amazonspider"
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1
start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_165993011_nr_n_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A165793011%2Cn%3A%21165795011%2Cn%3A165993011%2Cn%3A2514571011&bbn=165993011&ie=UTF8&qid=1493778423&rnid=165993011']


def parse(self, response):


    SET_SELECTOR = '.a-carousel-card.acswidget-carousel__card'
    for attr in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
        #print '\n\n', attr


        review_selector = './/*[@class="acs_product-rating__review-count"]/text()'
        link_selector = './/*[@class="a-link-normal"]/@href'

        if attr.xpath(review_selector).extract_first():
            if int(''.join(attr.xpath(review_selector).extract_first().split(','))) >= 800:
                url = urljoin(response.url, attr.xpath(link_selector).extract_first())


   next_page = './/span[@class="pagnRA"]/a[@id="pagnNextLink"]/@href'
   next_page = response.xpath(next_page).extract_first()
   print '\n\n', urljoin(response.url, next_page)

   if next_page:
       yield scrapy.Request(
           urljoin(response.url, next_page),
           callback=self.parse
       )
```